# How to allow Multiple Organisations deploying the same private app within Google Play Store

Tags: android, deployment, google-play

I am developing an app for the company I work for.  There is no plans to have it on Google Play Store. And for years we just provide an APK each release.

The organisations that use this App are many. Some are large and want to have a private App on a platform to distribution within their own organization (using Managed Google Play Store).  Each organisation may have different versions at different times.

What are my options please?

I have attempted some things and would be grateful if my assumptions where checked.

•   I believe the applicationId is found in the build.gradle

```
 `android { defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.X.Y'
        versionCode 9437
        versionName '2.8.5'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29 
    }
  }
```

`
•   I believe that the applicationId  needs to be unique throughout the public store and all private stores.
•   When I load my App into a managed google play store I get the error “Upload a new APK file with a different package name”. And conclude that someone else has loaded my App already.
•   When I do  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.X.Yt then no details are returned, so I assume that it is private app that was uploaded.

Leaving me to believe that publishing my App as a private App and allowing multiple organizations access is one option. Publishing my App in the public store and perhaps licensing it or protecting with a username/password is one option. And another is to continue giving the APK but each company having a unique applicationId.